# Célula com altura dinâmica no FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Quero criar um relatório com fpdf, mas toda vez que crio uma célula com algum texto grande, ela fica por cima da célula abaixo. Há alguma maneira de criar uma célula que se redimensiona automaticamente>

Answer (score 3):

No *fPDF* tem o `MultiCell`

- [Manual FPDF - MultiCell](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm)

Após muito tempo usando o *fPDF* eu migrei pro *mPDF* que é baseado no *fPDF*, porém melhor.
Permite o uso de tags HTML para criação (facilita muito na hora de montar, principalmente tabelas, mesclar conteúdos, imagens, posicionamento, etc), permite estilização com CSS, dentre outros recursos.

Consulte o site oficial:

- [Site Oficial do mPDF](http://mpdf1.com/)

Comment: Obrigado, vou da uma analisada na documentação do mPDF.

Answer (score 1):

Quando precisei de algo parecido usei o método `MultiCell` do FPDF.

Veja a documentação aqui: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

Edit:
Achei esse tutorial que pode ajudar http://www.limelightonline.co.nz/blog/create-dynamic-pdf-with-php-tutorial/